# Reversing a small synchronous gearmotor

Tags: raspberry-pi, home-automation, synchronous-motor

it's been difficult to find the answer to this problem I have. My project is based on home automation.

I need to control the direction of the rotation and if possible the torque of an AC synchronous motor like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B016J7TWF6) with the Raspberry Pi 2, to close and open curtains. 
The RasPi is already connected to a relay switch like [this one](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0057OC5WK) to automaticaly turn on some lights.

Does anyone know which is the best way to control the motor?

Comment: Post a link to a pdf data sheet of your exact motor and not to some purchasing site that you say is like the one you are using. Engineers work with the best information they can get and at the moment, what you have posted is pretty poor.

Comment: There's plenty of small gear DC motors around 4W  which would be an easier option, and probably much higher torque

Comment: @PeteKirkham thanks for the answer, thing is that I need to be able to select the direction of rotation. Could I do so with this small DC motors?

Comment: Yes, very easily with an H-bridge connected to two gpios ( one for direction, the other for on-off )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can make out that's the same type of motor used in a microwave oven for turntable drive. On startup they run alternate directions. The direction is not controllable. The fact that it's an AC motor with only two terminals gives us a clue that we won't be able to control direction.

I have wondered about why my microwave turntable reverses and found a good response by Sean B on [The Naked Scientist](http://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=47938.0):

> Most of the time they come to rest with one pole or the other nearest
>   the magnet pole, attracted to it. When power is reapplied this then is
>   repulsed, and as the gear set will have less friction in the reverse
>   direction ( the gears will have some slack play, when running this
>   makes it noisy but allows it to run freely, and when stopped it causes
>   a bias) and will tend to turn into that direction with less friction.
>   This then gives some momentum to the rotor and it carries on in the
>   same direction.

It's the wrong motor for your task.

[Update]

Crouzet make range of reversible motors of the type you had selected. The motors have two coils - one for clockwise and one for anti-clockwise rotation. See [here](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/ac-geared-motors/2044759/) for pricing and link to datasheet. Speed is way too slow for your application but it may give you some ideas.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgwA85.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Control circuit for reversible AC motor.*

**Stepper solution**

Steppers are great for simple position control provided the movement doesn't stall. For your curtain application this means that the motor needs to have adequate power to guarantee successful motion. For a stepper solution you will need:

- A suitable stepper motor.
- A suitable gearbox or pulleys to give adequate torque at a mid-range speed for the motor.
- A 'home' switch.
- Stepper driver module.

Sequence will be:

- On power-up drive the motor in the home direction (typically open) until the 'home' switch turns on.
- When closing the curtain you run the stepper the required number of steps to just close.
- When opening you can either move back the same number of steps or run the home routine again.

The stepper solution is more complex, noisier and requires additional low-voltage supply. The synchronous motor solution is simple and can be operated with a couple of switches. I'd be inclined to "keep it simple".

Comment: Thank you very much. So my solution would be to use something like a stepper motor?

Comment: Perhaps, but a gear motor and limit switches would probably be cheaper and lighter to mount.  Curtains probably only need precision in the range of a few mm so aren't sensitive to things like backlash in the way some other applications are.

Comment: Updated with schematic and link.